How does pytorch3d differ from kornia
For both the main point seems to be differentiability and written in pytorch, so why both?
I'm writing my master thesis and working with a library some former phd wrote that also does camera transformations. I have written some extensions to that, but instead of maintaining a separate library it would be useful to contribute that to one of the open source alternatives.
Is there any difference in design philosophy between kornia and pytorch3d?
